# Как вступить в приватный канал, используя telethon?

Tags: python, aiogram, telethon

Мне нужно вступать в приватные каналы с заявкой, используя библиотеку aiogram на python

Я используя вот такой код

```
    channel_entity = client.get_entity('название_или_идентификатор_канала')
    client(JoinChannelRequest(channel_entity))
```

У меня получается вступить в канал, если он публичный и имеет название по типу, topor907.
Но у меня не получается вступить в канал, если он приватный, с заявкой и имеет вот такую ссылку https://t.me/+O1q2XsgzeZxmY2Fk
Выдаёт ошибку

```
ValueError: Cannot find any entity corresponding to "https://t.me/+O1q2XsgzeZxmY2Fk"
```

Пробовал писать просто +O1q2XsgzeZxmY2Fk без https://t.me/

Answer (score 1):

Метод `JoinChannelRequest` подходит только для публичных каналов. Для приватных каналов нужно использовать `ImportChatInviteRequest`:

```py
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import ImportChatInviteRequest
updates = await client(ImportChatInviteRequest('+O1q2XsgzeZxmY2Fk'))
```

https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/examples/chats-and-channels.html#joining-a-private-chat-or-channel

Comment: Теперь я получаю ошибку. `telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.InviteHashExpiredError: The chat the user tried to join has expired and is not valid anymore (caused by ImportChatInviteRequest)
` Ссылка точно рабочая

Comment: Попробуйте указать хеш инвайта без знака "+"
(https://stackoverflow.com/q/58305760)

Comment: Помогло, спасибо. Но теперь я столкнулся с другой проблемой. Когда я пытаюсь применить данный метод к каналу с заявкой, то я получаю ту же самую ошибку. Есть ли метод для канала с заявкой?

Comment: К сожалению не нашел, либо не так понял